# how to troubleshoot a headless RPi4 that isn't reaching the internet (maybe isn't booting)

Tags: boot, pi-4

My pi4 has been hosting some web services at a friends house for a long time, but a few days ago it just went silent. I use [Tailscale](https://tailscale.com) as an intranet between my different machines, and Tailscale shows the pi as disappearing Jul 7, 3:51 PM, which is when I remember the web services going down. My friend has power-cycled it a couple of times, but nothing has happened. The Tailscale systemd service should start on boot, so if the pi successfully booted and got an internet connection it would connect to Tailscale. His router shows the pi as inactive, which makes me think the problem is not the ethernet connection.

The bad news is that my friend doesn't have a micro-HDMI cable to get any output for troubleshooting. What are the best methods for attempting to diagnose the situation?

Comment: I've tried asking if the green light is blinking in any sort of pattern as described [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151), but it seems like the flashes are just from reading the SD card. There's no regular pattern.

Comment: I guess `His router shows the pi as inactive` means `His router doesn't show the pi at all`? does the pi use a wifi or ethernet connection? The only way to diagnose a headless pi that has no network connection is to give it a head

Comment: It uses an ethernet connection. He's going to go buy a micro-HDMI adapter so he can plug a screen in